# Looping through multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach

I have VBA code that goes through a a range and changes the color of cells according to a predefined condition.  The code works for two rows (rows 3 and 4)  however, I want to use it another 98 Times.

```
Dim rCell As Excel.Range
Dim rRng As Range        
Set rCell = Range("AS3")

    For Each rCell In ws1.Range("AS3:BG3")
        If rCell.Value < Range("BP3").Value Or rCell.Value > Range("BO3").Value Then
            rCell.Select
            With Selection.Font
                .Color = -16776961
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next rCell

Set rCell = Range("AS4")

    For Each rCell In ws1.Range("AS4:BG4")
        If rCell.Value < Range("BP4").Value Or rCell.Value > Range("BO4").Value Then
            rCell.Select
            With Selection.Font
                .Color = -16776961
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next rCell
```

Comment: You want ```range("AS3:BG101")```?

Comment: `Set rCell = Range(...`: affectation is not useful since the variable is set again at the `For Each rCell ...` line. BTW, you should always be explicit when using Range. maybe you want `w1.Range(...` and not implicit *ActiveSheet.*`Range(...`

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want `range("AS3:BG101")` and the `IF` statement to reference the current `rcell` row. This should do it. I also removed your extraneous range setting and declaration as well as the selections.

```
Dim rCell As Range        

    For Each rCell In ws1.Range("AS3:BG101") 'Larger range
        If rCell.Value < Range("BP" & rcell.row).Value Or rCell.Value > Range("BO" & rcell.row).Value Then 'Variable value
            With rcell.Font 'No need to select
                .Color = -16776961
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next rCell
```

Comment: The code works as intended, Thank you. I am very new to VBA, most of what I know has been based of studying the resulting code from a recorded macro and my little experience scripting with Python. Thank you once again for your help